# Limit the amount of inputs in a Python list

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to set a limit to which the user can input names. This is where I got to and got stuck. How would I set a limit of 10 to the names the user can input into the list and restrict them from entering anymore?

```
names = [] 

print ('1 = Add Name ')
print ('2 = Display List ')
print ('3 = Quit ')

while True:

    option = input('What would you like to do: ')

    if option == '1':

        name= input('Enter name: ')

        names.append(name)
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Your code does not show an attempt to limit inputs. What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 2):

you can do :

```
if option == '1':
  names = [input('Enter name:') for _ in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that following script can help you:

```
# libraries
import sys

# list variable to store name
names = []

# limits to save name
limit = 10

# function to display menu
def menu():
    print("Enter 1 to add Name")
    print("Enter 2 to show list")
    print("Enter 3 to quit")
    choice = int(raw_input("Enter your choice : "))
    return choice

# running for infinite times till user quits
while(True):
    choice = menu()
    if(choice == 1):
        name = raw_input("Enter name to add in list : ")
        if(len(names) > 10):
            print("You cannot enter more names")
        else:
            names.append(name)
            print(name + " - Name saved successfully.")
    if(choice == 2):
        print("List of names : ")
        print(names)
    if(choice == 3):
        sys.exit()
```